# Why redis with protobuf is saving empty arrays as null?

Tags: c#, redis, protobuf-net, stackexchange.redis

I'm maintaining an application using protobuf-net ***2.3.3*** on a redis server ***2.8.2103*** using StackExchange.Redis ***1.2.6***.

For objects like:

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
public class Cachable { Foo[] Foos { get; set; } }
```

When I save using a simple:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, cachable);
    database.HashSetAsync("category", "key", memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

And then retrieve with:

```
var response = database.HashGet("category", "key");
if (!response.HasValue) return null;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(response, false))
{
    return Serializer.Deserialize<Cachable>(memoryStream);
}
```

If the cached array `Foos` had an empty instance, as in `new Foo[0]`, once `Cachable` is deserialized, the array become `null`.
This is changing the behavior of some part of application and generating errors.
Is this behavior expected? Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the real problem here the fact that `Foo[0]` is `null`? If so:

- protobuf *has no concept of `null`*; it cannot represent and store null, and so by default protobuf-net *skips* null values by default, making this *essentially* an empty array
- with the slight caveat of "empty packed primitives", protobuf has no concept of an "empty" sequence; in .proto terms, you're talking about a `repeated` field that has zero elements, which means : it simply doesn't exist in the payload **at all**
- and if it doesn't exist in the payload, it is never *deserialized* to anything - because there is never anything in the payload to *tell it* to deserialize

so:

- avoid `null` unless you mean for an optional sub-element; definitely avoid `null` in lists / arrays / etc
- don't assume that empty lists/arrays/etc will be initialized to non-null values *by the library*

IMO, the following would be reasonable and pragmatic for the second point:

```
Foo[] Foos { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Foo>();
```

(which avoids the issue of it initializing as `null`)